# Python not returning a decimal when expected

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal

```
scores = [20, 20, 20, 10, 9, 8]
if scores[0] == max(scores):
    win = (1/(scores.count(max(scores))))
    print win
```

I would expect this to return: 0.333

Instead it returns: 0

I put in some debugging code and confirmed that:

- The if condition is being met. The subsequent code is being executed.
- (scores.count(max(scores))) is returning a value of 3

So it would seem that win should obviously be set to 1/3, but it's being set to 0. I tried initializing the win variable as a float, but it made no difference.

Comment: Hmmm. It works in `Python3` properly, but in `Python2`, this happens.

Comment: Initializing a variable with a value of one type doesn't affect the type of anything you assign to it later.